# wicked_pdf generate pdf without fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation, wicked-pdf

I need to generate PDF, ready to be printed as report.
I use wicked_pdf gem.

My Controller:

```
render pdf: "file_name",   # Excluding ".pdf" extension.
      page_size: nil,
      page_width: 210,
      page_height: 297,
      orientation: 'Landscape'
```

My pdf.erb:

```
<body onload='number_pages' bgcolor="#ff00FA">
<div style="height: 210mm">
  <%= image_tag "https://static.pexels.com/photos/160699/girl-dandelion-yellow-flowers-160699.jpeg", width: "300px"%>
</div>
```

I made small sample to show my issue (see screenshot below).

I can't figure out how to make pdf without white fields around, I need body to fill all document.

Thank you!

[image: screenshot[![]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the margins to 0? Something like:

```
render pdf: "file_name",   # Excluding ".pdf" extension.
  page_size: nil,
  page_width: 210,
  page_height: 297,
  orientation: 'Landscape',
  margin:  {   
    top:               0,                     # default 10 (mm)
    bottom:            0,
    left:              0,
    right:             0 
  }
```

Comment: Glad that worked! I frequently have to go re-look at [Advanced Usage with all available options](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf#advanced-usage-with-all-available-options) to remind myself of these things.

Comment: Oh, also, if you're deploying on Heroku, you may end up running into memory problems if you're using the `wkhtmltopdf-binary` gem.

Comment: How to prevent memory problems?

Comment: I use [wkhtmltopdf-heroku](https://github.com/rposborne/wkhtmltopdf-heroku) instead of `wkhtmltopdf-binary`.